# How to specify a View's data binding context when using multiple view models

Tags: javascript, binding, mvvm, knockout.js

Let's assume we have few ViewModels with the same property names like `Id`, `Name`, also
we have defined a View template (basically HTML) and want to use/bind a data from both ViewModels.

Question is how to specify a binding data context so it would be a way to indicate from which View Model to use bound properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted on http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observables.html, optionally you can pass a second parameter to `ko.applyBindings` to define which part of the document you want to search for data-bind attributes. For example, `ko.applyBindings(myViewModel, document.getElementById('someElementId'))`. This restricts the activation to the element with ID someElementId and its descendants, which is useful if you want to have multiple view models and associate each with a different region of the page.

Another option would be to use the `with:` binding introduced on ko 1.3+, which renders the DOM based on a specific viewModel property. This is nice because if the property is null, nothing is rendered at all. Steve shared a live example about this feature on http://jsfiddle.net/StevenSanderson/f5w6u/3/light/

Comment: Great, `with:` is what I'm interested in, especially for nested ViewModels that's great thanks!